# How to get all data using month only

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
SELECT * FROM `EVENT` WHERE MONTH(START_DATE) = 7 AND YEAR(START_DATE) = 2019
```

How to use this query in sequelize with nodejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use range operators such as `$gte`, `$lte`, `$gt`, `$lt`:

```
model.findAll({
   where: {
     start_date: {
       '$gte': new Date("2019-07-01")
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: model.EVENT.findAll({
   where: {
     start_date: {
       '$month': 6
     }
   }
})